# Uniform distribution in glm R

Tags: r, glm

I have an experimental design with a continous dependent variable (DV), and two factors
A and B, factor A has 3 levels and factor B has 2 levels.
I checked my DV distribution with the function `descdist(DV)`, from the fitdistrplus package, and my DV is distributed as a uniform distribution.
In fact when I fitted my data into a uniform distribution with the function `fitdist(DV, distr="unif", method="mme")`, I found a perfect overlap.

My purpose was to run a Generalized Mixed Model, but given that uniform family distribution is not supported  automatically in the families of the  `glmer` function, I don't know how to fit properly the model so that it could take in account the uniform distribution of my DV

Have you any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This is probably a better fit for stats.stackexchange. I would suggest that you could try transforming your data - especially if you know theoretical max and min you could scale it to be in [0,1] and then use logistic regression

Comment: If you have questions about choosing an appropriate statistical model for your data, you should ask over at [stats.se]. Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions which this does not seem to be.